# Link to an external javascript file with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Excuse me, I'm very new to PHP and WordPress, but I'm trying to link to an exterenal js file called **trans.js**, that relies on jQuery. Here is the code at the beginning of the header.php:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/trans.js"></script>
```

and here is the enqueue within the functions.php

```
function twentytwelve_scripts_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;

    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwelve-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwelve_scripts_styles' );

function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/trans.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Yet it still does not link up with the **trans.js** — does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Does Firebug or Chome console reveal any error? Does the `<script>` tag show up in the HTML? How?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );

 function my_scripts_method() { 
    wp_register_script( 'my-first-script',   get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/trans.js', );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-first-script' );
}
```

Try this, i guess you dint register the script.